# Why Can't I Continue In Ternary Case?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

Why is it that the following does not work

```
        whichLibrary == undefined || "" ? whichLibrary = bookData : continue;
```

but the following does?

```
        whichLibrary == undefined || "" ? whichLibrary = bookData : console.log(`Do nothing.`);
```

Don't they effectively do the same thing? Is there something special about the Ternary operator, or the 'continue' keyword that I don't understand?

Comment: Even if this would work it would be a misuse of the conditional operator. Mashing everything into a single line isn't good for the readability/maintainability of your code.

Comment: @Ivar Are you saying it's better to use larger blocks of code that take up more vertical space? Isn't that clutter and thus bad practice?

Comment: It's most important that your code is easy to read and to understand. That makes it easier when you/someone else need to change it later and makes it less likely to introduce bugs. Having four different operators on the same line isn't easy to mentally parse. You have to carefully look what it does in order to understand it . Having too much (either horizontal or vertical) code into a single function also isn't optimal, but in that case you can always hide parts of it in new functions and store those functions elsewhere. With clear functions names, it is immediately clear what it does.

Comment: Having one "idea" per line usually makes for better readability. Half the time I use conditional operators I end up with it split over three lines.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator requires each of the three "positions" to be an *expression*. An expression is something built from the rules involving all the JavaScript operators, how variable and property references work, how function calls work, etc. But `continue` is not part of the grammar for expressions; it is a *statement*.

There are many parts of the language where expressions can go and statements cannot.

Comment: Oh, so is it fine for me to create something like: `whichLibrary == undefined || "" ? whichLibrary = bookData : 0+0;`  ? Or is there a better practice way of going about it?

Comment: Well you could always use an `if` statement. If you really must use `? :`, the last value can be simply `0` or `null`.

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operator has the format:

```
(condition expression) ? (expression when true) : (expression when false)
```

And it evaluates as one of the two right hand values depending on the left hand value.

The key is that everything must be an expression that evaluates to a value.

`console.log(...)` is an expression containing a function call that evaluates as `undefined` (and logs stuff to the console as a side effect).

`continue` isn't an expression. It's a control statement. It doesn't evaluate as a value at all.

---

In short: **The conditional operator is not a replacement for `if`**.